# Não consigo fazer push em repostório GIT

Tags: git, ssh

Tenho um repositório GIT em um servidor SSH e ao tentar fazer um push, acontece o seguinte:

```
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 1.35 KiB | 1.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/da/ffdcd5a57dd3f3b9d8aed54e4439dc0fe0a558: 
Permissão negada
error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/75/aa2521a79e4d6af862dce838331155aed96550: 
Permissão negada
error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/1c/0a5357051d2b326dc77e7e53fe7d1384c86ad1: 
Permissão negada
To ssh://192.168.0.5/opt/project.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unable to migrate objects to permanent storage)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://192.168.0.5/opt/project.git'
```

Notei que no repositório remoto, essas pastas são criadas com permissão de escrita apenas para quem as criou. Ou seja se outra pessoa fez um push e foram criadas essas pastas com permissão apenas para ela, quando eu tentar fazer um push e sobrescrever uma dessas pastas não vou conseguir.

[EDIT]
Percebi que no meu repositório local essas pastas são criadas com arquivos com permissão apenas para quem as criou, aí quando dou o push elas vão junto e se outros usuários quiserem sobrescrever não vão conseguir

Como fazer com que essas pastas não sejam criadas com permissão apenas para o dono?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um `git push --force` ? Comigo funcionou em uma situação, mas esteja ciente que ao fazer isso ele vai excluir tudo que está no repositório atual e substituir pelo conteúdo que você está tentando subir.

Comment: Você configurou SSH keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na hora de inicializar o seu repositório você deve instruir o `git` para que crie no modo compartilhado e como isso deve ser feito. Existem alguns modos de compartilhamento e suspeito que o padrão (grupo) seja o mais adequado para você:

```
$ git init --bare --shared=group opt/project.git
$ chgrp -R devs opt/project.git
```

Isso irá criar um repositório novo compartilhado entre o grupo de usuários **devs** no diretório `opt/project.git`.

Se você não quiser criar um repositório do zero, execute os seguintes comandos dentro do diretório `opt/project.git`:

```
$ chgrp -R devs .
$ chmod -R g+rw .
$ find -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
$ git config core.sharedRepository group
```

Para aprender mais sobre os modos de compartilhamento basta ler o [manual do `git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init).

Comment: Já tentei, notei que aqui no meu repositório local é que as pastas são criadas, com permisão apenas de leitura e quando eu faço o push elas vão junto com permissão de leitura, sem deixar os demais usuários sobrescreverem a pasta

Comment: Sim, para corrigir você deve rodar os comandos que eu listei no último bloco (onde tem as chamadas `chgrp`, `chmod`, etc)

Comment: Resolveu, obrigada!

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa saber qual o seu nível de permissão neste projeto. O dono do projeto possui permissão total então ele pode criar as pastas e decidir quem pode criar estas pastas também. O ideal é pedir a permissão para ele. A depender do seu nível você não consegue fazer o push no projeto principal, apenas na branch que você criou quando fez o pull.

Comment: não tem a ver com isso - tem a ver com permissões de arquivo do Unix no servidor git.